# how to access kafka.consumer metrics in a a spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

We are using Spark streaming in YARN mode to process data from a Kafka topic and wondering if anyone knows how to access (ideally via graphite) kafka.consumer metrics?